# Inject @Context HttpRequest

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture, jersey-2.0

I am working on RESTFul (JAX-RS) application and will be having a java class file in a jar file separated from war file which needs to access Headers from HttpServletRequest.

If the java class is in war file, i know i can access HttpHeaders using @Context in the resource method or on the resource class as
@Context
private HttpServletRequest httpRequest
OR i can listen to events from ServletListener and get the HttpHeaders as well.

Since the jar file SHOULD NOT depend on war file, i am not sure how to get headers from HTTPServletRequest.

Is there a possible way we can get HTTPheaders by annotations or CDI?

EDIT:
Actually, i need to get the header value (e.g., id) from the http request in WAR project (JAX-RS project, lets call it as WAR1) and then refer or use it in another java project(so that i can use it for processing some business logic or querying database) that can be copied or deployed as jar file to the WAR1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar file needs to depend on the javaee-api-x.0.jar and you need to have an empty beans.xml file in it. If you do that, you should be able to inject `HttpServletRequest` without any problems.

The version of the javaee api you use is dependent on the server you're using.